# As a statistical mathematician, does this upset you?

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Studying statistics I stumbled upon the ***cumulative distribution function*** being defined as

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/e5c664c7665277eea8f74575f4650fa933f28dcb

I thought to myself, why isn't it written the following way?

***for $x \leq a$***
***for $a \leq x \leq b$***
***for $x \geq b$***

So I asked a supporting teacher, and he wasn't 100% sure, but he jokingly said that doing this probably would upset a mathematician somewhere, thus the question in the heading. Would this upset you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your set of conditions doesn't upset me.  It does make me expect there is an error in your set of conditions.  Particularly, ...

The set of conditions you write is incorrect in the case $a = b$.  When $a = b$ in the original set of conditions, we find the CDF is zero to the left, one to the right, and undefined at $x = a = b$.  When $a = b$ in your set of conditions, we find that the CDF must simultaneously be $0$, $1$, and undefined at $x = a = b$.  Consequently, the original conditions are coherent when $a = b$ and your set of conditions are not coherent when $a = b$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I get the point you are saying, even though *a = b* is a little tricky special case to grip immediately. I must ask though, if my conditions are wrong, why doesn't it upset you?

Comment: @DonkeyKing : If wrongness *upset* me, I would spend all of my time upset, which is not a practicable way of living.  Also, I've made my own share of errors; we should expect that errors will be made by ourselves and others, while striving to minimise their number and impact.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)), the parameters are usually defined:
$$-\infty<a<b<\infty$$
and the interval can be closed, open or semi-open:
$$[a,b] \quad \text{or} \quad (a,b) \quad \text{or} \quad [a,b)$$ 
Hence, the CDF can be defined accordingly:
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x<a\\ \frac{x-a}{b-a},a\le x\le b\\ \ \ \ 1, \ \ b<x\end{cases} \\
F(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\le a\\ \frac{x-a}{b-a},a< x< b\\ \ \ \ 1, \ \ b\le x\end{cases}\\
F(x)=\begin{cases}\ \ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x< a\\ \frac{x-a}{b-a},a\le x< b\\ \ \ \ 1, \ \ b\le x\end{cases}$$
Note that the CDF is a piecewise function, whose domain must be non-overlapping. See [this](https://mathteachersresource.com/assets/piecewise-defined-functions---pdf.pdf).

So, probabilistically, both ways produce equal results: $x=a \Rightarrow F(a)=0$ and $x=a \Rightarrow F(a)=\frac{a-a}{b-a}=0$, however, the definition of piecewise function is violated.